# Mutual Information between multi-dimensional and single dimensional Variables

Tags: probability, distributions, information-theory, mutual-information

I would like to estimate MI between two variables `X` and `Y` of shape `(nXd)` and `(nX1)` respectively. As `X` is multi-dimensional (dimension = d) and `Y` is of dimsnension=1, is it a correct approach of the finding MI between each dimension of `X` against `Y` and adding each dimension's MI to get final MI?
Sample example:

```
X = rand[N,d]
Y = rand[N,]

for i=1 to d:
  mi_total += calculate_MI( X[:,i] , Y) #X[:,i] i_th dimension of X

# X[:,i].shape = (N,1) = Y.shape
```

Any help and correction is very much appreciated and Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically speaking, the following quantities are not equal in general, i.e. $$I(\mathbf{X};Y)\neq \sum_{i=1}^dI(X_i;Y)$$ Because, we are dropping out any dependence relationship. For example, if $\mathbf{X}=[X_1,X_1]$ (i.e. $X_2=X_1$), then the mutual information between $\mathbf{X}$ and $Y$ would be $I(X_1;Y)$, not $I(X_1;Y)+I(X_2;Y)=2I(X_1;Y)$. However, if the random variables inside $\mathbf{X}$ are independent, you can sum their individual MIs, as you've done in your code. I couldn't capture yours, but in many coding languages `rand` is assumed to create independent samples, in which you can really sum MIs.

Comment: Thank you. `X`  in my case is a dataset with `d` dimension, so I reckon it is safe assuming that each dimension is independent of each other and also the reason for using `rand`. I think my doubt is cleared :)